# How to create ACH Payments Using Stripe and Plaid?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, payment, plaid

I am trying to integrate **ACH payments via stripe and plaid** in there documentation there is no guide how to charge payments. i am stuck here

```
{
  "stripe_bank_account_token": "btok_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "request_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Can anyone help me please how to charge after retrieving these values succefully?

I have tried as we do normal stripe charge also but no luck. i think that is wrong approach an i was getting this error

```
  {charge: undefined,
  decline_code: undefined,
  payment_intent: undefined,
  payment_method: undefined,
  payment_method_type: undefined,
  setup_intent: undefined,
  source: undefined
}
```

I am using sandbox mode now.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, is your bank token really `btok_undefined` or did you just put that in the example to obscure your token? If it's actually `btok_undefined`, it doesn't seem like you successfully got a bank account token and will need to resolve that problem first before making a charge.

I found the following in the Stripe docs. Does this help? Note that if Plaid is in Sandbox, Stripe will need to be in test mode.

To create a charge on a verified bank account, use the stored Customer object the same way you would when using a card.

```
    curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges \
      -u sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc: \
      -d amount=1500 \
      -d currency=usd \
      -d customer=cus_AFGbOSiITuJVDs
```

You can mimic successful ACH charges using the following bank routing and account numbers:

Routing number: 110000000

Account number: 000123456789

Comment: No I am  not getting undefined, sorry that's just dummy i wil update my question, and stripe is also in `test` mode, what to do with `btok` and make charge a?  i am confused about that how to use `btok` to make charge with `node.js`

Comment: i am also able to get accounts detail, `account_id` and other data but do not know how to make charge ..

Comment: You'd want to create a Payment Method from the token and use Payment Intent API to create a payment or You can assign the Payment Method to a customer like Alex suggested.